# How can I create a dictionary that contains words from a text as keys and the "sublist in which it appears " as values?

Tags: python, search-engine

My question is quite similar to others but here my list is kind of special.

I have to create a search engine in Python. For that, I have to create a dictionary as I said in the title.

Let me give you the context:

I have basically a text which is made of several parts separated by "[==========]".

Like :

```
  [blablabla][blabliblou]
  [==========]
  [blablablou][blibloubla]
  [=========]
  [oubabababa][baboulila]
```

I created an algorithm that combine these lists until we "hit" a "=========="and put them into a single list where [blablabla blabliblou] is list[O], [blablablou][blibloubla] is list[1] etc...

The algorithm :

```
  import re
  file = open("mytext.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
  list = []
  dico = {}
  d = file.read()

  x = re.split(r"=+", d)
  for i in range(len(x)):
  liste.append(x[i])
```

I have an output like :

```
  [ [blablabla blabliblou] [blablablou blibloubla] [oubabababa baboulila] ]
```

But now the second step is to create a dictionary that has all the words of the text as key and the sublist(s) that contain them as value(s).

I tried to use a conditional loop as the following :

```
  import re
  file = open("mytext.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
  list = []
  numd = 0
  dico = {}
  d = file.read()

  for x in file:
  x = re.split(r"=+", d)
     for i in range(len(x)):
     list.append(x[i])
     numd =+ 1
        for word in list:
           if word in dico:
               if numd not in dico[word]:
                  dico[word].append(numd)
           else:
              dico[word] = [numd]
```

The expected output is :

```
    {blablabla:1, blablilou:1, blablablou:2, blibloubla:2, oubabababa:3,
baboulila:3}
```

but my list is still empty.

Thank you in advance for your reply! I would be so grateful

Comment: `{blablabla:1, blablilou:1, blablablou:2, blibloubla:2, oubabababa:3, baboulila:3}` seems a {word: count} dictionary. Is it?

Comment: What do you mean by "word:count dictionary" ?

Comment: in `blablabla: 1`, what does `1` represent?

Comment: In fact, I know how to create a word count dictionary, but my problem is that I have to combine it with the previous list that I created (it might be something wrong with it)

Comment: I have :            [ [blablabla blabliblou] [blablablou blibloubla] [oubabababa baboulila] ] so the "1" of blablabla : 1 means that blablabla is in the sublist number 1

Comment: ok now I understand

Comment: But it would be blablabla : 0 in fact instead of 1, this is my mistake

Comment: Did you check out the answer that I posted, does it fulfill your specifications?

Comment: I just saw it, I'll do : thanks a lot for you reply ! I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
from collections import defaultdict
all_dict = defaultdict(list)
for index, val in enumerate(x):
    for value in val:
        if value not in all_dict:
            all_dict[value].append(index)

print(all_dict)
```

It will get you the expected output:

```py
defaultdict(list,
            {'blablabla': [0],
             'blabliblou': [0],
             'blablablou': [1],
             'blibloubla': [1],
             'oubabababa': [2],
             'baboulila': [2]})
```

Comment: Thanks Piyush ! it almost works but the keys are the letters. The output that I have is like : { b : [0], l : [0]} etc

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [ ["blablabla", "blabliblou"], ["blablablou", "blibloubla"], ["oubabababa", "baboulila"] ]

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, line in enumerate(l):
    [d[word].append(i) for word in line]

print(dict(d))
>>> {'blablabla': [0], 'oubabababa': [2], 'blablablou': [1], 'blabliblou': [0], 'baboulila': [2], 'blibloubla': [1]}
```

Comment: the blabla text is not the text that I have to use but I used it as a example to make it easier to understand. So  I wrote : '    import re
from collections import defaultdict
file = open("docs-parl-mini.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
list = []
d = file.read()

x = re.split(r"=+", d)
for i in range(len(x)):
   list.append(x[i])

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, line in enumerate(1):
    [d[word].append(i) for word in line]'

I have the error message : for i, line in enumerate(1):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't really know how to put code parts in my messages

Comment: in `for i, line in enumerate(l)` it's a `l` (letter) not 1. But I think you will encounter other errors. First of all, you shouldn't use `list` as a name for variables, as it overwrite `list` method, and that's why you  get the next error

Comment: oh ok I fixed it ! And now I have : d = defaultdict(list)
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Comment: 'list = []'
'd = fichier.read()'

'x = re.split(r"=+", d)'
'for i in range(len(x)):'
  ' list.append(x[i])'                              This part of the code is the one that I wrote to create my list

Comment: you NEVER should use `list`, `dict`, `tuple` etc.. as names of your variables

Comment: What a mistake ! Thanks for telling me, I'm confused ! I'll correct

Comment: In my code `l`, that you have miswritten as 1, is the list of lists you get from your regex, `[ ["blablabla", "blabliblou"] ["blablablou", "blibloubla]" ["oubabababa", "baboulila"] ]`, so adapt your code appropiately

Comment: Yes don't worry ! I just wondered if it was something wrong with it

Comment: Could you please check my code above ? I updated it

Comment: It doesn't work as I would : the keys are the letters and the values are the sublists where the letter occur

Comment: can you post an example of a real list `l` ? Even just a couple of elements if too large

Comment: This is a sample of the basic text :                                  
En attendant, je souhaiterais que nous observions une minute de silence.
==========
Madame la Présidente, c'est une motion de procédure.
Vous avez probablement appris par la presse que des crimes immondes ont été perpétrés au Sri Lanka.
==========
Ma question porte sur un sujet qui est à l'ordre du jour du jeudi et que je soulèverai donc une nouvelle fois.
==========
À la demande d'un député français, Monsieur Doltelau, une pétition a déjà été introduite ; elle a récolté de nombreuses signatures dont la mienne.

Comment: l = { [En attendant, je souhaiterais que nous observions une minute de silence. Madame la Présidente, c'est une motion de procédure. Vous avez probablement appris par la presse que des crimes immondes ont été perpétrés au Sri Lanka.], [Ma question porte sur un sujet qui est à l'ordre du jour du jeudi et que je soulèverai donc une nouvelle fois.], [À la demande d'un député français, Monsieur Doltelau, une pétition a déjà été introduite ; elle a récolté de nombreuses signatures dont la mienne.] }

Comment: change `[d[word].append(i) for word in line]` to `[d[word].append(i) for word in line.split()]`

Comment: That works ! Amazing ! Just one more problem haha: do you have a function to  ignore symbols as : "(" , "." ? Because the algorithm assume "(situation" and "situation " as two distinct words. Would "strip() work ?"

Comment: the fast solution is to use `[d[word].append(i) for word in re.findall("\w+", line)]`, anyway I'd suggest to have a look at packages like https://www.nltk.org/ if your project is about text analysis

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's kind of you

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have so far :

```
  import re 
  from collections import defaultdict 
  file = open("mytext.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") 
  l = [] 
  d = file.read() 

  x = re.split(r"=+", d) 
  for i in range(len(x)): 
     l.append(x[i]) 

  d = defaultdict(list) 
 for i, line in enumerate(l): 
    [d[word].append(i) for word in line]
```

It seems to work but the keys are the letters and the values are the sublists where the letter occur